# Calculating distance is very slow

Tags: python, flask, geopy

I am working on a web app that shows users events near them. I have the below code that works but it is very slow in giving results.
I was wondering if there is anyway I can make it faster. It currently takes about 3 secs just to calculate the distance of 5 events. Here is my code snippet.

```
@app.route('/events')
def events():

    events = Post.query.filter_by(event=True, trivia=False, approved=True, featured=False).order_by(Post.datetime.asc()).all()

    geolocator = Nominatim()

    if current_user.state_1 != None:
        res_state = current_user.state_1
    else:
        res_state = ','

    user_city = geolocator.geocode(current_user.city_1 + ' ' + res_state + ' ' + current_user.residence)

    user_city = (user_city.latitude, user_city.longitude)

    events_near = []

    for event in events:
        if event.address_2 != None:
            address_2 = event.address_2+','
        else:
            address_2 = ','

        if event.state != None:
            state = event.state+','
        else:
            state = ','

        if event.zip_code != None:
            zip_code = event.zip_code+'.'
        else:
            zip_code = '.'

        location = geolocator.geocode(event.address_1+',' + ' ' + address_2 + ' ' + event.city+',' + ' ' + state + ' ' + zip_code + ' ' +  event.country )
        location = (location.latitude, location.longitude)

        distance = geopy.distance.vincenty(user_city, location).miles


        if distance < dist:
            events_near.append(event)

        return render_template('events.html', events_near=events_near)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any idea which lines are taking so long?

Comment: @Atto I am not really sure which line but I believe the ones with the geolocation wherein the lat and lng is calculated for the address.

Comment: Could give examples of what the variables in the `user_city = geolocator.geocode(current_user.city_1 + ' ' + res_state + ' ' + current_user.residence)` line could be?

Comment: @Atto Alla something like, user_city = geolocator.geocode('Oakland, California, United States'). It's basically getting the lat and lng of the user's city.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that this function is just slow (as it needs to query the internet), so not much can be done on your end

Comment: @Atto Allas yes it seems like it, do you know of any other ones that may be faster?

Comment: I have worked with one which seems slightly faster: pygeocoder. Sample code is `from pygeocoder import Geocoder` and `result = Geocoder.geocode("4207 N Washington Ave, Douglas, AZ 85607")` and then `coords = result.coordinates`, where `coords` is the lat and long of the address. Hope this helps! (Should I post this as an answer?)

Comment: @ Atto Allas  I have tried it and it's about the same, but you can add it as answer for someone that may be looking to have a different library from the one I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone looking to not use the module OP used:

I have worked with one which seems slightly faster: pygeocoder. Sample code is thus:

```
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
result = Geocoder.geocode("4207 N Washington Ave, Douglas, AZ 85607")
coords = result.coordinates
print(coords) # outputs the (lat, long) of the address as a tuple
```

I hope anybody looking to use this is helped!